# TeamCity email notification

Tags: batch-file, teamcity, freemarker

Currently on **TeamCity** we have a **Fortify** scan as one of the build steps.  Upon completion of the scan I parse through the `.xml` doc and get the vulnerability count from the scan.  As of right now the count is echoed back to the build logs in **TeamCity**.

My question is how can I take that vulnerability count and include that in the notification email?  I don't want to have to build a whole new email template for just a single variable that I want to include.  I know I can extend the notification template model, but is this the easiest way of adding the variable?  The **Fortify** scan is ran from a batch file, could there be an easier way to maybe set a global variable to retrieve the count in **TeamCity**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the number to the build status text by printing a line with the [service message](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus) into stdout:

```
##teamcity[buildStatus text='Fortify: <number>; {build.status.text}']
```

This way the result will be immediately visible in the list of builds nd the build notifications.